# Java xml parser compatible with android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, pandora

I am working on getting some of the code within this project to run as a Java Application instead of an Android app: https://code.google.com/p/pandoroid/

I am working on a Pandora client and would like to use the api developed within the project, however it seems to rely on some android dependencies when it comes to the xml parser.  can anyone recommend a library that would be compatible with minimum code editing?

errors revolve around:

```
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;
```

(I actually solved these by googling and finding the libraries)

and more importantly

```
import android.util.xml;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy using [XML Tool](http://code.mycila.com/xmltool/). It's a fluent API, so you can write short statements to accomplish what you need.